# How can I find unbalanced quotes in a text file?

Tags: shell-script

I have a text file with over 3 million lines and an unbalanced quote somewhere.  How can we find the unbalanced quote `" "`?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input, and expected output ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! We need more context to help you out. What do you mean by an "unbalanced quote"? An uneven number of quotes in the file? That alone wouldn't be enough to say where the mistake is. An opening quote that doesn't close on the same line? What kind of a file are you talking about? Text? A shell script?

Comment: I would like to see a shell script "with over 3 million lines".

Comment: @Paul_Pedant The questioner didn't say anything about a shell script.

Comment: @HaukeLaging No, but Martin did.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F\" 'NF%2==0 { print NR;; }' inputfile
```

gives you the number of all lines with an odd number of `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, finding balanced quoted strings, when the quote could be escaped `\"` [could become quite complex](https://regex101.com/r/4XKU5W/1/) to get exactly right, which makes it slow:

```
(?<=^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*("((?:[^\n\\"]|\\.)*+)"|'((?:[^\n'])*+)')
```

But if you care about only one type of quote (`"`), no double quotes `"` inside single quotes `'"'` and there is no escaping of the double quotes (`\"`) the problem becomes quite simple and, for the sake of speed, it could be solved with a simple and fast `tr` and `grep` pipe to get the line numbers where the number of double quotes is not even (odd):

```
➤ tr -cd '"\n' <file | grep -nxE '("")+"'
15:"""
16:"""
```

Answer (score 0):

This awk will find any line with an odd number of quotes, and print filename, line number and the first 80 characters.

```
awk '
  BEGIN { DQ = "\042"; fmt = "%s:%d:%.80s\n"; }
  gsub (DQ, DQ) % 2 { printf (fmt, FILENAME, FNR, $0); }
' file1 file2 ...
```

Depending on the syntax of the content, that may raise a few false positives, so check with an editor using the line numbers to find specific records.

Two or more close together could indicate a syntax where multi-line quoted data is permitted, such as a CSV field with an embedded newline in data.

Expanded to report unmatches single and double quotes:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { DQ = "\042"; SQ = "\047"; fmt = "%s:%d:%.80s\n"; }
  gsub (DQ, DQ) % 2 || gsub (SQ, SQ) % 2 { printf (fmt, FILENAME, FNR, $0); }
' file1 file2 ...
```

Comment: It may get interesting if quotes can be escaped `\"` or exist inside other quotes `"'"` or `'"'`.

Comment: @Isaac I did qualify with "depending on the syntax". However, we are told this is three million lines, so probably data, and escaped quotes would be unusual. CSV should not happen, for example, except for embedded newlines. The OP says "an" unbalanced quote. Pragmatically, if I had 3 million lines to search, I would be glad to reduce the problem to a few hundred cases with a simple one-liner. If that reveals an underlying syntax issue, we refine it. This is one of the reasons I use \042 in my awk scripts and not \" .